# Combine two RDDs in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Assuming that I have the following RDDs:

```py
a = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 5, 3])
b = sc.parallelize(['a','c','d','e'])
```

How do I combine these 2 RDD to one RDD which would be like this:

```py
[('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('d', 5), ('e', 3)]
```

Using `a.union(b)` just combines them in a list. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably just want to `b.zip(a)` both RDDs (note the reversed order since you want to key by b's values).

Just read the [python docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=zip#pyspark.RDD.zip) carefully:

> **zip(other)**
>
> Zips this RDD with another one, returning key-value pairs with the
>   first element in each RDD second element in each RDD, etc. Assumes
>   that the two RDDs have the same number of partitions and the same
>   number of elements in each partition (e.g. one was made through a map
>   on the other).

```
x = sc.parallelize(range(0,5))
y = sc.parallelize(range(1000, 1005))
x.zip(y).collect()
[(0, 1000), (1, 1001), (2, 1002), (3, 1003), (4, 1004)]
```

Comment: How would you do this if you had two RDD's with different number of elements and partitions?

Comment: Depends on the use case. One thing is sure - you need some key on which you want to do the join. Then you can proceed with eg. reduceByKey or join, like in this chapter - https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html