# How can I zip two RDDs in PySpark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have been trying to merge the two Rdds below averagePoints1 and kpoints2 . It keeps throwing this error

```
ValueError: Can not deserialize RDD with different number of items in pair: (2, 1)
```

and I tried many things but I can't the two Rdds are identical, have the same number of partitions . my next to step is to apply euclidean distance function on the two lists to measure the difference so if any one knows how to solve this error or has a different approach I can follow I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

```
 averagePoints1 = averagePoints.map(lambda x: x[1])
 averagePoints1.collect()
 Out[15]:
 [[34.48939954847243, -118.17286894440112],
 [41.028994230117945, -120.46279399895184],
 [37.41157578999635, -121.60431843383599],
 [34.42627845075509, -113.87191272382309],
 [39.00897622397381, -122.63680410846844]] 

  kpoints2 = sc.parallelize(kpoints,4)
  In [17]:

  kpoints2.collect()
  Out[17]:
  [[34.0830381107, -117.960562808],
  [38.8057258629, -120.990763316],
  [38.0822414157, -121.956922473],
  [33.4516748053, -116.592291648],
  [38.1808762414, -122.246825578]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newSample=newCenters.collect() #new centers as a list
    samples=zip(newSample,sample) #sample=> old centers
    samples1=sc.parallelize(samples)
    totalDistance=samples1.map(lambda (x,y):distanceSquared(x[1],y))
```

for future searchers this is the solution I followed at the end

Answer (score 3):

```
a= [[34.48939954847243, -118.17286894440112],
 [41.028994230117945, -120.46279399895184],
 [37.41157578999635, -121.60431843383599],
 [34.42627845075509, -113.87191272382309],
 [39.00897622397381, -122.63680410846844]] 
b= [[34.0830381107, -117.960562808],
  [38.8057258629, -120.990763316],
  [38.0822414157, -121.956922473],
  [33.4516748053, -116.592291648],
  [38.1808762414, -122.246825578]]

rdda = sc.parallelize(a)
rddb = sc.parallelize(b)
c = rdda.zip(rddb)
print(c.collect())
```

check this answer
[Combine two RDDs in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35085740/6358543)

Comment: kpoints2 is a sample from an RDD average points is the mean points from the RDD and I will be writing a while loop till convergence so this solution won't help. do you have any other ideas please !